# CasperJS - echo cyrillic symbols

Tags: encoding, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I use `echo()` function for output text to stdout. But instead of the cyrillic characters are displayed incorrect characters. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. It should run the script with command line parameters:

```
--output-encoding=cp866
```